# Access an array in object property, Sequelize

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, sequelize.js

I've got a form with entry that you can multiply, so we have some inputs with the same name. So my req.body.input returns an array. Here is a test request object:

```
{
     "artist": "Picasso",
     "title": "Les demoiselles d'Avignon",
     "yearBegin": "1902",
     "yearEnd":"1936",
     "period":"Début XXème",
     "width":"200",
     "height":"65",
     "technical":"Peinture à l'huile",
     "support":"Bois", 
     "isSigned":"true",
     "status":"En cours d'authentification",
     "tags":"",
     "galery":["Perrotin","Moma",""],
     "exhibitionName":["Lalala","A dog in Berlin",""],
     "exhibitionBegin":["2018-04-01","2018-03-01",""],
     "exhibitionEnds":["2018-04-30","2018-03 28",""],
     "localisation":"Allemagne",
     "description":""
}
```

I want to loop on req.body.exhibitionName for example, but when i loop as:

```
for (var y=0; y < req.body.exhibitionName.length; y++) {
   exhibitionController.create(req,res, idCreation, y)
}
```

And in my controller i've got :

```
module.exports = {
    create(req, res, id, i) {
      Exhibition.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
        return Exhibition
          .create({
              name: req.body.exhibitionName[i],
              galery: req.body.galery[i],
              dateBegin: req.body.exhibitionBegin[i],
              dateEnd: req.body.exhibitionEnds.[i],
              idExhibitionCreation: id
          })
        })
    }
};
```

And it push me in the database for the first entry galery = P, then galery = E and all the letter in the first value of my array....So my question is how i can get data from the array inside my object property and loop on the array ?

Comment: I think if you `console.log(req.body)` you'll see `galery` is a string not an array of strings. This is based on `req.body.galery[i]` giving a single letter.

Comment: yes that was a part of the problem, i had to make an if statement to check if the data returned is an array or a single string, then i treat them differently, one with an index, the other without. i thought that result[0] return the data even if it is a single component. But no, instead it split the result in separate letters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your for loop won't wait for the promises to be fulfilled so you need to use the `each` function from the `async` library on NPMJS.

`package:`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

`documentation:`
https://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: And your comment won't fix it because the async is being ignored. If the OP uses the async module then the rest of the solution will be clear.

Comment: @ChrisSharp thank you, your response save my life ! It works !!!!! Sorry Jamiec but ChrisSharp is right ! I now have the good entries in my database !

Comment: @KimRose I'm glad it worked out :) You can mark it correct if you like.